# R: boxplot reorder differently in two facets

Tags: r, boxplot, facet

I have measurements over two seasons (summer and winter) of one parameter:Formaldehyde with different sensors( A1, B2,B3,...F21).
Data looks like this:

```
sensor=A1,A1,A2,A2,A3,A3
Formaldehyde=21.3,34.2,55,66.3,70.8,90
Season= summer,winter,summer,winter,summer,winter
```

I am trying to make a geom_boxplot divided into two facets( one for each season) and I want the sensors to be ordered by increasing median (independently in each season)
I have tried:

```
fac <- with(DATALL, reorder(sensor,Formaldehyde, median, order = TRUE))
DATALL$sensors <- factor(DATALL$sensor, levels = levels(fac))

a <- ggplot(DATALL,aes(sensors,Formaldehyde, fill=sensors)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(colour=factor(sensors)), alpha=0.4) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  facet_wrap(~season, scales='free', ncol=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = quantile(DATALL$Formaldehyde, c(0.1, 0.98)))
a<-a+labs(x="",y=expression(Formaldehyde~(30~min)~(µg/ m^{3})))+theme(legend.position = "none")
```

But this orders the sensors considering the median of both seasons and not for each facet independently.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: Hello Maria, can you submit a dataframe with similar structure as your DATALL please, to help users reproduce your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use some code from this post: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets

```
DATALL <- data.frame(sensors=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3"),
                     Formaldehyde=c(21.3,34.2,55,90,66.3,71.8,22.3,44.2,65,90,69.3,79.8,25.3,35.2,45,70,56.3,80.8),
                     season= c("summer", "winter"))


DATALL <- merge(
  # merge your dataset...
  DATALL %>% 
    # adding a column with season and sensor index
    unite(index, c("season", "sensors")),
  # ... to a column giving the order of sensors by season
  DATALL %>%
    group_by(season, sensors) %>%
    summarise(Formaldehyde = mean(Formaldehyde, na.rm = T)) %>%
    arrange(Formaldehyde) %>%
    mutate(order = row_number()) %>% arrange(order) %>% 
    # create the common row index
    unite(index, c("season", "sensors")) %>% select(index, order)) %>%
  separate(index, c("season", "sensors"))


ggplot(DATALL,aes(factor(order, levels = min(order):max(order)),Formaldehyde, fill=sensors)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(colour=factor(sensors)), alpha=0.4) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~season, scales='free', ncol=1) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = DATALL$order,
    labels = DATALL$sensors,
    expand = c(0,0))DATALL <- data.frame(sensors=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3"),
                     Formaldehyde=c(21.3,34.2,55,90,66.3,71.8,22.3,44.2,65,90,69.3,79.8,25.3,35.2,45,70,56.3,80.8),
                     season= c("summer", "winter"))


DATALL <- merge(
  # merge your dataset...
  DATALL %>% 
    # adding a column with season and sensor index
    unite(index, c("season", "sensors")),
  # ... to a column giving the order of sensors by season
  DATALL %>%
    group_by(season, sensors) %>%
    summarise(Formaldehyde = mean(Formaldehyde, na.rm = T)) %>%
    ungroup() %>% arrange(season, Formaldehyde) %>%
    mutate(order = row_number()) %>% arrange(order) %>% 
    # create the common row index
    unite(index, c("season", "sensors")) %>% select(index, order)) %>%
  separate(index, c("season", "sensors"))


ggplot(DATALL,aes(factor(order, levels = min(order):max(order)),Formaldehyde, fill=sensors)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(colour=factor(sensors)), alpha=0.4) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~season, scales='free', ncol=1) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = DATALL$order,
    labels = DATALL$sensors,
    expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "sensors")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Rosalie,
Unfortunately , when I use your code , it does not work equally well when adding more data. If I add some extra data:

```
DATALL <- data.frame(sensors=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3"),
                     Formaldehyde=c(21.3,34.2,55,90,66.3,71.8,22.3,44.2,65,90,69.3,79.8,25.3,35.2,45,70,56.3,80.8),
                     season= c("summer", "winter"))
```

the figure that is output with your code looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk1oT.png)

Comment: Hello Maria! Just saw you answer here. It's better if you use the "comment" section in the future so the initial person posting gets notified!
I edited my answer (see above). Let me know if it works!

Comment: Great! Can you validate the answer above then? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Sorry, I'm a beginner with Stackoverflow!